# Why does a "GLib-WARNING" message briefly appear on-screen when entering or leaving suspension?

Tags: suspend, 10.10, glib

I see the following on-screen for a brief moment when entering or leaving suspension:

```
(process:###): GLib-WARNING **: getpwuid_r(): failed due to unknown user id (0)
```

Any idea what this is, how I can get rid of it, and if it's something I should be concerned about? It's been happening ever since I installed 10.10 64-bit (fresh install) - I don't recall it ever happening under 10.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to worry about and happens to all users, as far as I am aware.  It's actually there when you boot too, just covered over by Plymouth and then by your login screen.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think it was something to worry about, though I have to wonder what Canonical changed between 10.04 and 10.10 that caused the error to start showing up. Operating systems hoping to compete with Microsoft and Apple in terms of user-friendliness shouldn't be showing scary-sounding terminal warnings to end-users.

Comment: It was present in 10.04 as well.  Lots of bug reports exist for 10.04 where people think that's an error that's making their computer not boot, when really it's a warning that just happens to be there and is visible for more-than-half-a-second if their computer fails to boot properly.

Comment: Specifically on my machine (a Lenovo X201), I'm almost 100% sure this error was never visible in 10.04, or if it was, it was on-screen for far less time that it is now.

Comment: Is suspend/resume overall slower for you in Maverick?